# Difference in weight from Cura to printed model

Tags: creality-ender-3, ultimaker-cura, petg

I've recently switched to PETG , and I'm using Cura as slicer and Ender 3 as printer.

I'm printing a model which Cura declares to be **35 g**, but if I weigh the printed model it weighs **23 g**.

I'm printing with just 1 line of skirt, so its weight is negligible on total weight.
I've replaced the stock plastic extruder with a double gears metal extruder (3Dman 11 Dual Gear Extruder ).

[image]

I've also replaced the stock springs with metals ones.

I'm not having a quality problem, just I want to understand if this difference is caused by a bad configuration that could be improved.

Which are the corrections/checks that I need to do in my setup (both printer and Cura) for fixing this difference?

Comment: In case Cura is being stupid, look at the final E-axis value in the output gcode file to see how much material it's attempting to extrude. Multiplying it by 2.4 ((1.75/2)² × pi) will give the volume of material in mm³ which you can then multiply by the expected density.

Comment: Also: Is it possible there's priming-line, skirt, brim, raft, or support material you're not counting?

Comment: Good guess, but I'm printing just 1 line of Skirt, just for clearing the nozzle... 
totally negligible, I guess. Btw I'm adding this information to the question, might be useful.

I'm looking for the value you are referring to tomorrow and I'll post you back, thanks

Answer (score 3):

The density of the filament can be specified in the material model of the filament in Cura (Preferences -> Configure Cura... -> Materials and click on the material/filament you are using to slice your model for PETG), look at the value behind *Density*, the PETG filament I use is using 1.28 g/cm³ ([PETG Economy Black -> Specification >](https://colorfabb.com/petg-economy-black)).

[image: Cura materials window]

This field is user editable, so you can change it to your needs. Cura calculates the weight based on the deposited volume.

Comment: Thanks for your answer: I've setted the density to 1.27 , but I'm now getting 37gr, which leads to a bigger difference. Is there any other possible problem?

Comment: This setting is used to allow the viewer to determine expected filament use for the print. As you've already discovered, an inaccurate figure will present a disparity between the displayed value and the weight of the print. Changing the numbers will only provide for a value difference, not an operational difference. The other answer (currently) is not likely to be correct, unless you are having model quality problems.

Comment: @fred_dot_u actually I'm not having a quality problem: I'm only trying to understand if my printer is printing correctly or if something is not right setted. This difference has raised a warning in my mind...

Comment: I didn't think you were having a problem with quality, as that would have taken priority, in my opinion. The answer referencing underextrusion appears to be off-base for that reason. If you use trial and error to enter a weight value in the settings, until you get something that matches closely enough, you'll have done no harm.

Answer (score 2):

Likely underextrusion. The Ender 3's extruder is particularly bad at PETG and slips a lot unless you go really slow, like 3 mm³/s (about 40 mm/s at 0.2 mm layers and 0.4 mm line width) or lower.

For a long time I thought this was a limitation of the material, at least without a really powerful hotend, and wondered why anyone liked it. But after replacing the extruder on my Ender 3 with one that grips the filament much better (among other differences) I can extrude at several times that rate with no extrusion issues.

My extruder has a lot of differences from the stock Creality one that might be making a difference. It's (remote) direct drive, has a cut-out hobbed gear that wraps partly around the filament tensioned rigidly rather than with a spring, and has net 10:1 reduction gearing. I suspect the hobbed gear configuration makes the biggest different to increased PETG printing capability but I'm not sure. Here's a picture of what I'm talking about

[image: hobbed filament gears]

Comment: Actually I'm printing at 40mm/s , because that's the only way I've found to be able to work with petg and ender 3... and the first layer I'm lowering it to 10mm/s ...
Which extruder are you suggesting to upgrade to?

Comment: I'm not making a particular recommendation because there are lots of factors to weight choosing what you want and product recommendations are off topic for this site. I have a flex3drive remote direct drive but it's some work getting it setup well. Mainly for this specific problem I suspect you need either double hobbed gears (both sides of filament) or a hobbed gear cut to wrap halfway around the filament. Mine uses the latter and I suspect it's the better choice.

Comment: You might even be able to get away with just replacing the hobbed gear in the stock extruder, but some reduction might also be needed to increase torque too.

Comment: I've already mounted a double hobbed gears... and actually I'm not having a problem of quality in prints (just some filaments)... how can I measure if my printer is printing the right amount of filament?

Comment: This should be another question/answer pair... https://letsprint3d.net/how-to-calibrate-the-extruder-steps-ender-3-5-cr-10/ will show you how to check the extrusion values for your printer.

Comment: @Leviand: Can you show a picture of the extruder gear setup you're using or name/link the specific product if it's something commercially available?

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE I've added an image in the question, the name is "3Dman 11 Dual Gear Extruder ". I've never done a calibration before, I will give a try!!!